# How to change this navbar color?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble changing the color of the following navbar.
I want to change the background color, it is in grey, i would like in light blue for example
I have tried adding a style attribute on my navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="">
```

`style="color:#ADD8E6"`

but it doesnt work

here it is

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQ92SC7PE45P

Could someone help me out ? Thanks

Comment: search for navbar class and change the color properties there.

Comment: Using bg-* class. Ex : bg-dark, bg-primary, bg-secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it via inline styling, just add important after your style, it will work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color:red !important;">
```

Comment: Works as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

those classes (navbar-light bg-light) maybe changes the background color 
anyway you can add rule for .navbar class with !important flag to make it happen

```
<style>
.navbar {
background-color: #112233 !important
}
</style>
```

or you can use pre defined colors such as 
bg-primary
bg-info
bg-danger
bg-warning
bg-success

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work in two ways,
1. write your css code
2. white in html as you have done

1. write your css code
   Add a class in the nav bar, like `mytheme`

and white this css code

```
.mytheme {
background-color: #add8e6 !important;
}
```

2. or do it your way

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: #add8e6 !important">`

Answer (score 0):

try changing the inline css property of the nav tag
try this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:10px">
```